# Horizontal line inside a matrix

Tags: equations

I tried to make a horizontal line inside a matrix by the attached code. However, it didnot work the compiling process gives a time out message. It work normally without the \hline command. Any help!

```
\documentclass[journal,draftcls,onecolumn,12pt,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
\centering
W_b(1)=\begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
\begin{block}{(ccccc)c}
 a      & b     &     &  &  & \matindex{\leftarrow d=0} \\
\ddots & \ddots&     &  &  & \matindex{\vdots} \\
   &     a & b   &  &  & \matindex{\ \ \ \   \leftarrow d=d_b-1} \\  
%\hline
 c      & d     &     &  &  & \matindex{\leftarrow d=d_b} \\  
\ddots &\ddots &     &  &  & \matindex{\vdots} \\
   &   c   &  d  &  &  & \matindex{\leftarrow d=D} 
\end{block}
\end{blockarray},
\label{eq:eq4} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please provide a complete example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, and in particular provide the definition of `\matindex`.

Comment: Sorry for the missed part. I added them now

Comment: @AhmedYahia: Does the code as provided compile for you?

Comment: Definition of `\matindex` is still missing.

Answer (score 1):

See, if the following solutions gives what you after:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
W_b(1)=\begin{blockarray}{(cc cc c)l}
\bigstrut[t]
a       & b         &   &   &&   \leftarrow d=0     \\
\ddots  & \ddots    &   &   &&   \vdots             \\
        & a         & b &   &&   \leftarrow d=d_b-1 \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-5}
 c      & d         &   &   &&   \leftarrow d=d_b    \\
\ddots  &\ddots     &   &   &&   \vdots              \\
        & c         & d\bigstrut[b] &   &&   \leftarrow d=D      \\
\end{blockarray}
    \end{equation}
or
    \begin{equation}
W_b(1)=\begin{blockarray}{(cc cc)l}
\bigstrut[t]
a       & b         &   &   &   \leftarrow d=0     \\
\ddots  & \ddots    &   &   &   \vdots             \\
        & a         & b &   &   \leftarrow d=d_b-1 \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-4}
 c      & d         &   &   &   \leftarrow d=d_b    \\
\ddots  &\ddots     &   &   &   \vdots              \\
        & c         & d\bigstrut[b] &   &   \leftarrow d=D      \\
\end{blockarray}
    \end{equation}    
\end{document}
```

[image]